# My PhD supervisor doesn't guide my project, and I am concerned about my progress

Tags: phd, advisor

I am doing a very technical computational STEM PhD, which has been very wide open to me in terms of what direction I take it. I have 2 supervisors. One supervisor has always been very responsive but he only knows the clinical side, the second supervisor is very technical but has never been responsive.

I previously had a supervisor (previous research, now left this) who very closely reviewed my work and constantly pushed me, and I did very well with them. I saw the way they managed their PhD students and they always provided them with continuous feedback, made arrangements for them to work with postdocs to learn skills, and guided the overall progress and structure of their work, i.e. 'next analyse this', try this statistics etc. Their PhD students did extremely well also. I think my previous supervisor did think I should be more independent though. But he was very much a manager of our research.

My current supervisor had the notion of "see what you can do!" and "I don't have time to manage you". It is quite nice to have total freedom, but I feel like I have completely floundered. When I started the PhD I was confident I could progress as a PhD student, which I have somewhat lost and feel mediocre. Although I have learned a lot over the 2 years, and some technical skills which are very marketable, I just don't feel I am anywhere near publishing a first author paper. I would love for my supervisor to guide me more. I wish he had some goal for me, but his focus is mostly elsewhere.

My supervisors had been trying to apply for a large dataset, which I was using a small portion of. That was one of their main focus. That fell through and so did my use of the dataset, so I also don't really have much data for a computational PhD. Recently I heard my supervisor had acquired a small slightly different dataset (different animal, same organ) and given it to a postdoc in another group to analyse. Another group offered to let us analyse their data, but my supervisors turned it down (I presume because they were concerned they would lose control of authorship etc). My supervisor gives more attention to a collaborator PhD student who he doesn't supervise, who he says is "very talented".

I had been trying to make the best of the situation, and find ways to publish. Part of me feels that maybe if I was just better I would be able to publish. But I also think that it's pretty unwieldy challenge for a PhD student to have minimal data + minimal direction. Though the working environment is honestly very nice, pleasant. I feel like I can probably produce something that passes as a PhD, but I am struggling to conceptualise + implement research papers myself. Any thoughts? FYI other people also comment that my supervisor is quite minimal in involvement etc.

tl;dr wish I was getting more specific direction in PhD project, any advise?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.